# Strange Error in using consolelog in nodejs

Tags: node.js

Using node.js 0.10.24.
I got an error telling me that `"Object has no method log"` in 6th line in following code.
But when 3rd line enabled, no problem. Anyone know why?

```
var EE=require("events").EventEmitter;
var on=EE.prototype.on;
//var c=console;

EE.prototype.on=function(event,handler){
console.log("added "+event);
on.call(this,event,handler);
};

var server=require('http').createServer();
```

Comment: Seems like your code is overriding `console` somewhere.

Comment: No. It is all. And I dont know why when using var c=console; no error message by nodejs.

Comment: I guess that monkeypatching `EventEmitter.prototype.on` leads to all sorts of weird behaviour.